# Intermittently slow CPU performance in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, performance, aws-lambda

Consider the following AWS Lambda function:

```py
import time
import pickle
import gc

def ms_now():
    return int(time.time_ns() / 1000000)

class Timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = ms_now()

    def stop(self):
        return ms_now() - self.start

with open('model_embeddings.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    model_embeddings = pickle.load(file)

def get_embeddings(texts):
    timer = Timer()
    embeddings = model_embeddings.encode(texts)   # The line of interest
    print(f"Time: {timer.stop()}ms")
    return embeddings

def lambda_handler(event, _):
    gc.disable()                                  # Disable garbage collection
    result = get_embeddings(event['texts']).tolist()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'result': result[0][0], 
    }
```

The function is deployed as image and is given 10,240 MB of RAM, of which only 800 MB is used. The function outputs the timing of a single line that performs a CPU-intensive task of running input strings through a neural network (HuggingFace sentence transformer) that has been initialized and loaded into memory.

I run this function repeatedly with the same input from AWS Lambda console. The output time is usually around 350ms. However, some runs are as slow as 2100ms. Note that these spikes cannot be explained by either cold starts (since only one line's performance is being measured) or garbage collection kicking in (since garbage collection is disabled).

What can cause such spikes?

**EDIT 1.** I ran it locally (under WSL under Windows) and never got such a high spike. So it must be something AWS Lambda - specific...

**EDIT 2.** Today I cannot reproduce the spikes with the above. However, if I return `result` in the response instead of `result[0][0]`, then it's slow. Now this is really strange. What does the size of the response have to do with the line I am timing? (For some background: `texts` is a list of 114 strings. `embeddings` is a NumPy matrix with 114 rows and 384 columns. `tolist()` converts this matrix into a list of lists.)

**EDIT 3.** If I use a short input first, the problem disappears! Namely:

```py
# Pre-warming. I have no clue why it helps to avoid spikes!
timer = Timer()
embeddings = model_embeddings.encode(texts[:1])
print(f"Time: {timer.stop()}ms")

timer = Timer()
embeddings = model_embeddings.encode(texts)
print(f"Time: {timer.stop()}ms")
```

What is going on?

P.S. The [question at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU188JSeI_QGK2e83vodXyYw/intermittently-slow-cpu-performance-in-aws-lambda)

Comment: As usual: instrument to run with a profiler, analyze the slow profile outputs (you can output them into S3, for instance).

Comment: (Or https://aws.amazon.com/xray/ maybe.)

Comment: A Lambda runs inside of an EC2 environment.  It is ultimately a shared resource - a VM inside of possibly another VM.  Between this shared resource and the use of an interpreted language I would expect to see some variation in runs.  I've never used Lambda for consistency in multiple runs but rather parallel processing where the overall "answer" is as fast as possible and for times when I don't want to spin up my own EC2.

Comment: @stdunbar That's exactly my case. In the actual production setting, I run eight instances in parallel. The problem is that when seven of those instances run in 300ms and one takes 2000ms, the overall answer takes 2000ms...

Comment: @AKX I ran it locally (under WSL under Windows) and never got such a high spike. So it must be something AWS Lambda - specific...

Comment: By running a profiler of some sort, you may be able to hone in on what exactly occasionally takes so long, and that'll give you more clues.

Comment: You say that it's not a cold start issue because "only one line's performance is being measured", but in a language such as Python (or Java) that relies on lazy-loading, the cold start penalty covers the _entire_ application. Any line of code might incur an extra cost the first time it's run. The only way to determine that it's _not_ a cold start penalty is to look at the logs and verify that it is the second (or subsequent) invocation for a particular Lambda execution environment.

Comment: And to answer your comment from the question you deleted: this update provides the necessary context. People looking at it can see what, exactly, you're timing. And can potentially run it themselves.

Comment: @AKX The line in question is a call to PyTorch, which is just an interface to Torch, which is written in C.

Comment: @kdgregory Thank you for pointing out about dynamic loading. In any case, I run it in the AWS Lambda Console and know that it is not a cold start (a cold start is also very noticeable in my case as it takes some six seconds).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Funny. I can't find an `encode` function in PyTorch's reference manual. (Also, PyTorch is not "just an interface to Torch", anyway; there's 1.17 million lines of Python in the PyTorch repository and 779k lines of C++).

Comment: @AKX Ah, I was imprecise. The model is a HuggingFace sentence transformer model. The `encode` method uses PyTorch internally. I guess I had it wrong about the relationship between PyTorch and Torch. In any case, how can profiling help when what slows things down is happening in the environment and not in PyTorch?

Comment: Because if the profiler says it's occasionally taking an anomalous amount of time in e.g., I don't know, `prepare_foobars`, you could see if you could pre-prepare the foobars.

Comment: @AKX Why would the effect of something happening in the AWS Lambda environment only affect part of computation?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Presumably the `encode()` call (and whatever happens within) is the longest-taking part of your execution anyway, so by sheer probability if something is stalling the processing of the lambda at all, it'd happen there. I'm not sure why you seem so reluctant to measure your code to get some hard facts and numbers, and instead we're talking theoreticals here.

Comment: @AKX I cannot reproduce the spikes with this code now. However, if I return `result` in the response instead of `result[0][0]`, then it's slow. Now this is really strange. What does the size of the response have to do with the line I am timing?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning What makes you think it's about a size? Right now `embeddings`seems to be some data type (you're not giving us much clues as to what) with a `.tolist()` method... For instance, if actual evaluation of whatever happens in `.tolist()`, you're not measuring it at all.

Comment: @AKX `texts` is a list of 114 strings. `embeddings` is a NumPy matrix with 114 rows and 384 columns. `tolist()` converts this matrix into a list of lists. But the call to `tolist()` should be irrelevant for the timing of the single line about which I am asking and which takes almost all of the total running time of this Lambda function. Also, please see edits 2 and 3!

Comment: @kdgregory Please see **EDIT 3**. What do you think?

Comment: "I have no clue why it helps to avoid spikes!" You might have a clue if you profiled...

Comment: I think that differences in observed results are more likely the result of methodology than underlying conditions. You seem fixated on this being an issue with the Lambda execution environment. And while that is _possible_, it is extremely unlikely that you have managed to turn up a significant, random, and _frequent_ performance degradation in a system that has been around for nine years. If there was such a systemic issue, then people with more resources than you would have been screaming at their TAMs to get it fixed.

Comment: @kdgregory I am timing a single line, which invokes [one of the most popular models](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2) out there. So, I don't see space for an issue here so much. On the other hand, AWS Lambda is known to have idiosyncrasies (cold starts being one of them). Some of the idiosyncrasies are not documented (e.g. [proactive initialization])(https://aaronstuyvenberg.com/posts/understanding-proactive-initialization). So I believe that what we are looking at here is another one of those and I want to find out what it is.